# Pandas command unintentionally shifting data between rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a integer column called TDLINX. I'm trying to convert that to a string with leading zeros such that all values are 7 characters, with leading zeros. So 7 would become "0000007"

This is the code that I used:

```
df_merged_total['TDLINX2'] = df.TDLINX.apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(7))
```

At first glance this appeared to work, but as I went further down the file, I realized that the value in TDLINX2 was starting to get shifted. What could be causing this and what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: Please show a self-contained example demonstrating your problem.

Comment: if your indices are not aligned between `df_merged_total` and `df` then you will observe an offset what does `df_merged_total.index.difference(df.index)` show?

Comment: You're right. That's definitely the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"col":[1, 33, 555, 7777]})
>>> df["new_col"] = ["%07d" % x for x in df.col]

>>> df

    col  new_col
0     1  0000001
1    33  0000033
2   555  0000555
3  7777  0007777
```